# Page router and livecycle

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, nativescript

hopefully this is understandable :)
In my app I'm using the page-router-outlet together with Typescript and angular-js. Currently the app feels unresponsive because the routing is done after the target page is build up completely.
The change I would like to do in my app is to start the navigation while the page is beeing build and then lazy initualizing the content.
Is there a best practice how to do this?

I tried different livecylcehooks from ngInint to ngAfterViewChecked and several in between, the pagerouter seems to ignore them and only router after everything is done.

Has anyone an idea on how to lazy build up the page?

Greetings

Torsten

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the question, but it seems you are asking about the Angular Router with Nativescript. In which case, you have two choices, the `<page-router-outlet>` which you are currently using, this loads up everything page by page, creating the slowest outcome, whereas you could structure your pages to use the [`<router-outlet>`](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/navigation-angular.html#router-outlet) which allows you to navigate through sub-components.

So you might, for example, have a toolbar component and a footer component, which you don't need to ever change, so you might consider only using routeing to change the body. This means potentially far less information is being loaded. I think this is sort of the point of the ng2 component system.

Here is a generic example fo the component router in action:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from 'nativescript-angular/application';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'nativescript-angular/router';

import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "./app.routes";

@Component({
    selector: 'navigation-test',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="nav">
                <Button text="First" 
                    [nsRouterLink]="['/first']"></Button>
                <Button text="Second"
                    [nsRouterLink]="['/second']"></Button>
            </StackLayout>

            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class NavigationApp {
}

nativeScriptBootstrap(NavigationApp, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi George, yes, the router-outlet would improve the situation a little bit, but it isn't working with the hardware-back-buttons on android, the page-router-outlet works fine.

Comment: The router-outlet is an angular "nested" element which is why it is not registered with the {N} navigation. I am not sure if there are plans or if its even possible to map that outlet to the {N} navigation stack.

The way that I use the router-outlet is for content that should be refreshed rather than navigated to. For navigation I aways use the page-router-outlet.